# Google Sheets time stamp to not appear when row is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found a script to automatically create a time stamp when any change is made to a row in Google Sheets.

```
function onEdit() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() != 2 )
    {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var time = new Date();
        time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+04:00", "dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('q' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
    };
}
```

However, I don't want it to create a time stamp when the entire row is empty.

How do I make the timestamp not appear when the entire row is empty?

Comment: Try adding an if/else statement to check if the row has a value or not before placing a timestamp. This will make sure that you'll only place a timestamp for data populated rows.